# synchronise simple html list with a drop down list in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-lists

i want to synchronise a simple html list, like the one below with a drop down list in a form

```
    <div id="navcontainer">
     <ul id="navlist">
     <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>


     #navlist li
     {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

meaning that, for any selected element from the list, using a javascript, i want to be able on one side to memorise the selected item, and on the other part to update the elements in a drop down list. is it possbile?

thank you!

edit:

having this code, i want to display for each product the maximum value of his stock in the select list, when the product is selected

```
  <script>  
    $(function ()
    {
        var $select = $('#mySelect');

        $('#navlist li a').live('click', function ()
        {
            $select.val($(this).text());
        });
    });
    </script>

      <form name="add-to-basket" method="post" action="<?= Route::url('Add to Basket',              array('sale_id' => $sale->id)); ?>">

     <? foreach ($types as $type):?>
     <div id="navcontainer">
     <ul id="navlist">        
         <li value = "<?=$type->stock_2 ?>"><a href="#"><?= $type->label;?><?= $type->stock_2;?></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>

   <? endforeach; ?>

   <select name="number" id="mySelect">
   <? for ($i = 1; $i <= $type->stock_2; $i++): ?>
  <option <?= $type->stock_2 == $i ? 'selected="selected"' :''?> value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></option>    
   <? endfor; ?>

   </select>
   </form>
```

Comment: How would the user "select" the elements from the li? A simple click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/gukh2

I hope it's not this what you want because if someone else buys an item while another person is doing the same, the javascript will not have the accurate count of items.  This does not seem to me a javascript only job.

#### HTML

```
    <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="#" class="current">Item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Stock</h2>
        <select id="myStock" size="5" width="50px">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Cart</h2>
        <select id="myCart" size="5" width="50px">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br class="clear"/>
    <h2>The effect on the items object (unaffected)</h2>
    <span id="items"></span>
    <h2>The effect on the stock object</h2>
    <span id="stock"></span>
    <h2>The effect on the cart object</h2>
    <span id="cart"></span>
```

#### CSS

```
a {
    font: bold 100% "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 5px;

}

#navlist li a.current
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #555;
    font: bold 120% "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.box {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
        var stockItems ={"Item one":2,"Item two":5,"Item three":9,"Item four":13,"Item five":14};//stock object
        var cartItems ={"Item one":0,"Item two":0,"Item three":0,"Item four":0,"Item five":0};//cart object
        var originalItems ={"Item one":2,"Item two":5,"Item three":9,"Item four":13,"Item five":14};//items object

        $("#navlist li a").click(function() {
            $("#myStock option").remove(); //reset the stock dropdownlist on click
            $("#myCart option").remove(); //reset the cart dropdownlist on click
            var itemName; //name of the item
            var total_stockItems = stockItems[$(this).text()]; //get total stockitems for an item
            var total_cartItems = cartItems[$(this).text()]; //get total cartitems for an item
            if (total_cartItems < originalItems[$(this).text()]) {//total amount of cartitems for an item has to be lower than the initial amount for that item, you can't buy more than there is.
                cartItems[$(this).text()] += 1; //counter, updates the cart-object +1
            }
            if (total_stockItems > 0) {//total amount of stockitems for an item has to be higher than 0 for to be able to add it to the cart
                stockItems[$(this).text()] -= 1; //counter, updates the stock-object -1
            }

            for (itemName in (stockItems)) {
                if (stockItems.hasOwnProperty(itemName)) {
                    $("#myStock").append($("<option></option>").val(stockItems[itemName]).html(itemName + ": " + stockItems[itemName] + " piece(s) in stock")); //build the stock dropdown
                }
            }
            for (itemName in (cartItems)) {
                if (cartItems.hasOwnProperty(itemName)) {
                    $("#myCart").append($("<option></option>").val(cartItems[itemName]).html(itemName + ": " + cartItems[itemName] + " piece(s) in cart")); //build the cart dropdown
                }
            }
            //some info on the objects
            $("#items").text("var items =" + JSON.stringify(originalItems) + ";"); //output the items object
            $("#stock").text("var stock =" + JSON.stringify(stockItems) + ";"); //output the current stock object
            $("#cart").text("var cart =" + JSON.stringify(cartItems) + ";"); //output the current car object
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm giving up on this question. I simply don't understand what the OP wants. +1 for sticking with it.

Comment: it is super cool... but still.. not what i was wondering. i just need a drop down list in which i can catch the sale_stock variable(meaning that in the drop down i will have something like 1,2,3,4,5 where 5 is the number of products in the sotck), for each product in the list. the code is what i have pasted above. thank you!

Comment: i am not trying to udate the stock from javascript. i am just trying to pass to a drop down list a php value: the stock of products. which is different for every product.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you are trying to do.  Pls make hardcoded in html what you want as end-result and make a screenshot of this, add it to your question.  If you do I'll give it one more shot but that's it. I just don't get it, and it seems I'm not the only one here.

Comment: yess!! it is something like that!! jsfiddle.net/stofke/qkpQu  but, with no update of the stock on click. i just want the stock number to be displayed, that;s all :) no javascript update on stock.

Comment: i am just wondering how i can set the "Item one": 2,
        "Item two": 5 dynamically (in php maybe? is it possible? )

Comment: also it would be awesome if i would have a single drop down list, in which the stock display takes place, at click event

Comment: <?php
    $arr = array ('item one'=>1,'item two'=>2,'item three'=>3,'item four'=>4,'item 5'=>5);
    echo json_encode($arr); // {"item one":1,"item two":2,"item three":3,"item four":4,"item five":5}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function:

```
    function itemClicked(item) {

        // Check that the item is not already in the dropdown
        var itemsDropdown = document.getElementById("items");
        var alreadyPresent = false;

        for(var i=0;i<itemsDropdown.childNodes.length;i++) {
            var childOption = itemsDropdown.childNodes[i];
            if(childOption.nodeType == 1 && childOption.text == item.text) {
                alreadyPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Add option to dropdown
        if(!alreadyPresent) {
            var newItem = document.createElement("option");
            newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.text));
            itemsDropdown.appendChild(newItem);
        }

        // Toggle the current item
        document.getElementById("current").id = "";
        item.id = "current";

        return false;
    }
```

You need to add it to the onclick event of each list item:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current" onclick="return itemClicked(this);">Item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return itemClicked(this);">Item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return itemClicked(this);">Item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return itemClicked(this);">Item four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return itemClicked(this);">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You also need to add a dropdown box:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <select name="items" id="items">
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is tagged `jquery`, so I would assume a jQuery solution is wanted.

Comment: its cool, but how can i clear a form list element after i have clicked on it?? thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the list item that was clicked on? Just add this to the end:

document.getElementById("navlist").removeChild(item.parentNode);

Comment: nope, i mean to be able to change the options. now, if i click on something it is selected, but if i click on another, it doesn;t get selected... it remains onlt the first selection